# Multithread Write byte[] into file

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, filestream

I hoping someone can help me, if have a question about writing into a file using multiple threads/Tasks. See my code sample below...

AddFile return a array of longs holding the values, blobNumber, the offset inside the blob and the size of the data writing into the blob

```
public long[] AddFile(byte[] data){
    long[] values = new long[3];

    values[0] = WorkingIndex = getBlobIndex(data); //blobNumber
    values[1] = blobFS[WorkingIndex].Position; //Offset
    values[2] = length = data.length; //size

    //BlobFS is a filestream
    blobFS[WorkingIndex].Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    return values;
}
```

So lets say I use the AddFile function inside a foreach loop like the one below.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(System.Environment.ProcessorCount);
foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents"){
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        long[] info = blob.AddFile(data);
        return info
    });
    task.ContinueWith(// do some stuff);
    tasks.Add(task);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray);
return result;
```

I can imagine that this will totally fail, in the way that files will override each other inside the blob due to the fact that the Write function hasn't finished writing file1 and an other task is writing file2 at the same time.

So what is the best way to solve this problem? Maybe using asynchronous write functions...

Your help would be appreciated!
Kind regards,
Martijn

Comment: .NET 4.5 will provide asynchronous file I/O natively, at the moment it's better to keep things synchronous (you're writing to the same physical drive anyway, so operations cannot be parallelized in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here would be to *not* run these tasks in parallel.  It's likely that disk IO will be the bottleneck for any file-based operation, and so running them in parallel will just cause each thread to be blocked accessing the disk.  Ultimately, you'll quite possibly find that your code runs significantly slower as you've written it than it would run in serial.

Is there a particular reason that you want these in parallel?  Can you handle the disk writes serially and just call `ContinueWith()` on separate threads instead?  This would have the benefit of removing the problem you're posting about, too.

**EDIT:** an example naive reimplementation of your `for` loop:

```
foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents"){
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(file); // this happens on the main thread

    // processing of each file is handled in multiple threads in parallel to disk IO
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        long[] info = blob.AddFile(data);
        return info
    });
    task.ContinueWith(// do some stuff);
    tasks.Add(task);
}
```

Comment: I just want to get the maximale performance out of my application. I need to handle a huge amount files and every step in my process I can improve will hopefully speed-up the process. But you are right that this could cause a I/O bottleneck. Could you explain what you mean by "Can you handle the disk writes serially and just call ContinueWith() on separate threads instead?" Tnx!